# If condition cannot evaluate multiple "True"s - Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3D numpy array called `BNodeVal`. Currently its size is `(1,1,16)`, but it can be bigger than this. I am trying to evaluate an `if` condition using this 3D array and 3 coordinates `coord_x , coord_y, coord_z`.

`BNodeVal = [[[ 0.      1.     15.      0.      0.     13.4     1.77   15.9
    1.77   37.391   1.03   40.931  39.161   0.5402  0.      0.    ]]]`

Below is that portion of the code that is not working correctly:

```
for j in range(int(np.amax(BNodeval[i, :, 1]))):
    print("x = ", coord_x, "\ny =", coord_y, "\nz =", coord_z)
    print("3 = ", BNodeval[i][j][2], "\n4 =", BNodeval[i][j][3], "\n5 =", BNodeval[i][j][4])
    print(np.isclose(coord_x, BNodeval[i][j][2]))
    print(np.isclose(coord_y, BNodeval[i][j][3]))
    print(np.isclose(coord_z, BNodeval[i][j][4]))

    if np.isclose(coord_x, BNodeval[i][j][2]) and \
       np.isclose(coord_y, BNodeval[i][j][3]) and \
       np.isclose(coord_x, BNodeval[i][j][4]) :  # 1 - 1
        print("# 1 - 1")
    else:
        print('# 1 - 2")
```

This is what it is printing :

```
x =  15.0 
y = 0.0 
z = 0.0
3 =  15.0 
4 = 0.0 
5 = 0.0
True
True
True
# 1 - 2
```

However, if i only use one of the `np.isclose` terms, it just work fine and print `# 1 - 2` instead. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: But you *reset* `BNodeval` before the actual `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks but that is `BNodevalue` not `BNodeval`

Comment: Seems to me that that is not the best way to name your variables. You are asking for confusion like that.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I am editing the varaibles now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last test is wrong. You are printing:

```
print(np.isclose(coord_z, BNodeval[i][j][4]))
```

But testing:

```
np.isclose(coord_x, BNodeval[i][j][4])
                 ^ should be z
```

Comment: Thanks I don't know how I miss this.